# How to change the style of the default WooCommerce sorting selectbox

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I didn't find the default styling of the selectbox for sorting products i WooCommerce especially appealing. So i decided to change it with CSS. This only worked half-way.

Problem:
The select-element did accept my style changes, but the actual dropdown with options didn't. I simply would like to change the appearance of the dropdown with some css-changes.

This is what I want to achieve:http://jsfiddle.net/pioul/2wdgH/

...for this page: http://sandbox.inspirapress.com/kaizen/butikk/

This is the general markup I have to work with:

```
<form class="woocommerce-ordering">
<select>
<option></option>
<option></option>
<option></option>
</select>
</form>
```

The js and css files(jquery.simpleselect.js/css) seem to enqueue correctly in header and footer. I'm not quite sure about the inline script i the footer though...

I've now tried just about everything. Please help! :)

//André

Comment: Can you provide me with a link to the site page where you are trying to apply these changes.

Please Explain what u tried for achieving the styling? an live example giving with link/screenshots will be helpful for me to suggest you a solution

Comment: @WisdmLabs I just updated the post with examples!

Comment: Have looked at your SITE.Inspecting the same analysed that there are  errors in js which you can see by using developer tools, it has 2 js errors.

Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function(anonymous function) @ simpleselect-controller.js:1
sandbox.inspirapress.com/:636 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function(anonymous function) @ sandbox.inspirapress.com/:636

CODE 1:

$(".orderby").simpleselect({
    fadingDuration: 500,
    containerMargin: 100,
    displayContainerInside: "window"
});

CODE 2:

$(".orderby").simpleselect();

USE "jQuery" instead of "$" in the above codes. Check if it works